# Why doesn't the client receive the response message from the server?

Tags: javascript, go, request, cors, fetch-api

I want to make a simple client-server application. I'm completely new to this. The client part should be written in JavaScript, while the server should be written in Go. The problem is that when I click on the button after starting the server and client parts, I get HTML code on it. It seems I'm setting the port incorrectly or there's an error in processing the response from the server side in the client side. Or maybe I launch the client side incorrectly.

I use Visual Studio Code for both Go and HTML-CSS-JS. When checking to start the server without the client part, I get a message from it (it works fine). Then I launch the client using Live Server in VS Code. And when I click on the button I get a response in the form of my HTML code. The correct operation of the application is to receive a server response to the button when I click on it.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5500")
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(data => {
            btn.textContent = data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error:", error);
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple application</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Press</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Go code**

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5500")
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello from the server!")
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":5500", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("Server started on port 5500")
}
```

Comment: make sure you dont run both client and server on same port.

Comment: is one server bound to `computer_ip:5500` and the Go Code bound to `localhost:5500`

Comment: The Web origin you need to allow in your CORS configuration corresponds to that of the client, but you seem to have mixed it up with the Web origin of the server. As a result, you're most likely observing a CORS error in your browser, which refuses to let the client access the response.

Comment: And if your client and server happen to both run on `http://localhost:5500`, there should be no need for CORS.

Comment: I've changed fetch("http://my_computer_ip:5500") to fetch("http://localhost:5500") and deleted w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:5500"). The problem remains the same.

Comment: @ac3gbsha7 If your client does not run on `http://localhost:5500`, you'll still need to set at least a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Comment: Yes, Camilo Urán helped me, I've tried this solution, and it works. Thank you as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code locally and got a CORS error. Change your header in `func handler` to this:

`w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`

and the error should disappear. The way you have it, you're telling the server "allow connections from localhost:5000" but that's not the port that the browser is using to make the request. That's the destination port, of the server. Your browser will just use a random port number for the connection, for example in my case I saw this error in the Dev Tools:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5500/' from origin 'http://localhost:63343' 
has been blocked by CORS policy
```

Which means, the browser is using port 63343. Just use `*` and the server will know that it needs to allow connections from all origins.